# Max K-product of the numbers

Tags: c++, algorithm, max, product, modulo

Task - Max K-product of the numbers
Time Limit: 1
Memory Limit: 64 M
Given a sequence of integers N (1 ≤ N ≤ 10 May, | A i | ≤ 2.10 9) and the number of K (1 ≤ K ≤ N). Find K sequence numbers whose product is maximum.

Input data:
The first line contains two integers N and K.
In the second line lists the N elements of the sequence A.

Output data:
Derive the maximum product. So the answer may be quite large, output it modulo 10^9+7.

Example
The result of the input data
3 2
-2 -3 3

Answer - 6

Below is my attempt. It is a mistake, that's what I do not know. Can you help find a mistake in my decision?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
typedef vector<int> v1;
const int mod = 1000000007;
int n, k, pos1 = 0, pos2 = 0, negative = 0;
long long res = 1;
void QuickSort(v1 &a, int l, int r) {
  int i = l, j = r, pivot = abs(a[l + ((r - l) >> 1)]);
  do {
        while (abs(a[i]) < pivot) i++;
        while (abs(a[j]) > pivot) j--;
        if (i <= j) {
            int temp = a[i];
            a[i++] = a[j];
            a[j--] = temp;
        }
    } while (i < j);
    if (l < j) QuickSort(a, l, j);
    if (i < r) QuickSort(a, i, r);
}

long long product(v1 &a, v1 &b, int q, int j, char flag) {
    long long res = 1; int temppos;
    if (flag == 0 && j) {
        temppos = b[pos1];
        b[pos1] = j;
    }
    if (flag == 1 && q) {
        temppos = b[pos2];
        b[pos2] = q;
    }
    if (!pos2 && (k & 1)) {
        for (int i = 1; i <= k; i++)
            res = (long long)((res % mod)*1ll*(a[i] % mod)) % mod;
    } else {
        for (int i = 1; b[i] != 0; i++)
            res = (long long)((res % mod)*1ll*(a[b[i]] % mod)) % mod;
    }
    if (flag == 0 && j) b[pos1] = temppos;
    if (flag == 1 && q) b[pos2] = temppos;
    return res;
}

int main()
{
      v1 a(100002, 0);
        v1 b(100002, 0);  //index multiplied to the elements
        cin >> n >> k;
        for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) cin >> a[i];
        QuickSort(a, 1, n);
        for (int i = n, j = 1; i > n - k; i--) {
                b[j] = i;
                if (a[i] < 0) {                     
                    pos1 = j;    //index last positive number 
                    negative++;  //increase the counter negative numbers
                }
                  else pos2 = j;  //index last positive number                
                j++;
        }
        int j = n - k, q = j;
        if (negative & 1) { //If an odd number of negative numbers
            while (j > 0 && a[j] < 0) j--;
            while (q > 0 && a[q] > 0) q--;
            res = max(product(a, b, q, j, 0), product(a, b, q, j, 1));
        } else res = product(a, b, q, j, 3);
        cout << res << endl;
    cin >> res;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: A high-level description of your attempt would be helpful (in addition to your code, or just the high-level description).

Answer (score 0):

First off: your code is very dense and confusing, so I'm gonna give my own approach and thought processes here.

So my first thought was about the case where all the input integers are positive. Call our source array (the one containing the N integers) A.

- Initialise an array B containing the first K elements from A.
- For each i such that K <= i <= n, check A[i] against each element in B. If A[i] is larger than some B[j], replace B[j] with A[i].
- When you're done, multiply the contents of B together modulo 10^9 + 7.

This takes O(KN) time, so if K grows slower than O(lg(N)), it's faster than your quicksort as well as simpler. You could possibly improve the time bound to O(N lg(K)) by using a tree or heap to store B, but that's going above and beyond the call of duty.

The problem with my solution is that the question gives negative numbers as inputs. Now if by "Answer - 6" you mean "the answer is -6 = -2 * 3", and you're asking for the largest magnitude product, all you need to do is take the magnitude of each input number in the above procedure. But your code indicates you meant "the answer is 6 = -2 * -3", in which case things are a little more complicated.

See, if the maximal product contains two (or an even number) of negative integers (like the example of (6 = -2 * -3)), my method wouldn't work, because the sorting routine chucks negative numbers to the bottom of the list.

Instead what we need to do is keep three arrays: A, our input array; B, an array of the K **largest positive** numbers encountered so far; and C, an array of the **smallest negative** (to avoid confusion: in the list -2 -3 -4, the two smallest negative numbers are -3 and -4) numbers encountered so far.

When we've extracted B and C using a routine similar to the one above, we need to combine them. The best way I can think of of doing this is to sort both B and C first, then

- Calculate the product of all the numbers in B modulo 10^7+9. Record this as MAX.
- Replace the two smallest numbers in B with the two smallest (most negative) numbers from C.
- Again calculate the product of all the numbers in B, and if it's larger than the current MAX, update MAX.
- Replace the two smallest **positive** numbers in B with the **next** two smallest numbers from C.
- Repeat until you've gone all the way through C.

This takes O(K^2) or thereabouts, and again you could maybe speed this up with a smarter approach (say stopping the substitution when the magnitude of product of the negative number pair you're inserting is smaller than the product of the positive number pair you're replacing), but this is the clearest one I could think of.